# How to read jpg-image's orientation with Adobe AIR on a mobile device

Tags: android, ios, mobile, air, blackberry-playbook

My problem first seemed to be quite trivial to me first, but yet I didn't find a satisfying solution:

The use-case is: 
I load jpgs from 'CameraRoll' or 'CameraUI' to be displayed inside my app.
Although the picture might have been taken in all possible device orientations, I want them always to be rotated correctly to fit my app. Sounds simple.

Problem:
Certain OSes seem to ignore the orientation in the file metadata when opening them in AIR. E.g. Samsung Galaxy Tab running Android 4.2 always displays them in landscape orientation. BlackBerry PlayBook works fine. iOS doesn't give me access to the original file but passes a bitmap-copy, which is "landscape only", too.

Although I might be able to read the exif data on Android, this will AFAIK not work on iOS.
Adding manual "rotate" buttons to my UI might be a solution, too, but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [An exif Extractor Libary for Actionscript 3.0](https://code.google.com/p/exif-as3/)?

Comment: Well, not actually tried ... but this can only work, if I have access to the actual file, which iOS denies ... or is there anyway to get the images other than 'CameraRoll', which returns blank BitmapData (without exif)? I might implement different solutions for different OS,though. EXIF for Android, Buttons for iOS ...

Comment: Oh ok, no idea. Sorry for hijacking your question, I can delete my "answer".